# Why is this SELECT line with CAST, CONVERT and FORMAT not working?

Tags: mysql, sql

Very new to SQL and having some trouble understanding what part of this statement is causing an error. There is a db named ap, with a table named invoices with a column named invoice_table. The textbook says I should be able to write a single select statement to return the 4 columns, invoice_total, a FORMAT on invoice_total with 1 decimal point, a CONVERT of invoice_total as an INT and a CAST of invoice_total as an INT. But I get an error 1064 every time I try to run it. Running mysql workbench with Innodb as dbms.

```
USE ap;
SELECT invoice_total, 
    FORMAT(invoice_total, 1), 
    CONVERT(invoice_total, INT),
    CAST(invoice_total AS INT)  
FROM invoices
;
```

Comment: `There is a db named invoices` I guess you meant table named invoices.

Comment: This should generally be structured in the `FROM` statement as [database].[schema].[table], assuming `invoices` is your table, this needs to be restructured.

Comment: Which dbms????  It's probably one of the most important piece of information that you can give!!!

Comment: Have you even read the documentation for the dbms you are using???

Comment: Apologies, I didn't include some necessary info. The invoices table is in the ap database. In mysql workbench using Innodb as the dbms, I omitted the code line USE ap;

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, that cannot CONVERT or CAST to INT. Only to SIGNED or UNSIGNED.

Comment: Worked, thank you, the textbook needs to have its exercise questions rewritten. Appreciate the help.